# pythonic way to find if a list with duplicate items contains at least as many copies of each element of another list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Hi I have two lists `req` and `sup` each of may have duplicates and req can be empty.  I wanted a pythonic way to test that `sup` has all copies of each item in `req`.
As an example I would want a function contains with the following functionality:

```
requirements = [['a','b','b'],['a','c'],[]]
supplys = [['a','b','c'],['b','b','a','c']]
for sup in supplys:
    print(sup)
    for req in requirements:
        print(req)
        print(contains(req,sup))
    print()
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'b']
False
['a', 'c']
True
[]
True

['b', 'b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'b']
True
['a', 'c']
True
[]
True
```

What I currently have just seems to verbiouse, and I feel like there should be a way to do this as a one liner.

```
def contains(req,sup):
    flag = True
    for letter in set(req):
        if self.sup.count(letter) < req.count(letter):
            flag = False
    return flag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one-liner I as able to come up with for any who discover this question later:
`all([req.count(letter) <= sup.count(letter) for letter in set(req)])`

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient. Don't aim to write one-liners, *write efficient algorithms* The problem with your code wasn't verbosity, as written, is is perfectly pythonic, you did not make it *more* pythonic by putting it on one line. but the algorithm, again, is inefficient.

Comment: Ehh context matters.  My code sint gunna be used in any particularly high performance operations and I prefer the readability of a single line conditional then method call.  Anyway its not like the code in this example is less efficient then the code I used previously both are O(set(req)).